# Website zooming on Android

Tags: android, html

[My website](http://iqhomeautomation.com/) looks great on iPhone but zoomed in on Android. I've got the standard device width code in the header (and I've used this for all websites I've done and they look fine) but for some reason this isn't working on Android and the website seems to be majorly zoomed in.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

I want it to look like the way it does on iPhone. So when it loads you can see the whole width.

[image]

Like this here.

Yet on the android it does this...

[image]

Anyone have advice as to why it's zoomed in on Android and how I can fix this weird tweak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the width to the actual width of your site, rather than the device with.

For example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=980">
```

Also, I'd suggest getting a good book on HTML/CSS and working your way through.

Edit: [O'Reilly's 'Head First' HTML & CSS](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Head-First-HTML-Elisabeth-Robson/dp/0596159900) is *extremely* easy to follow, but will also give you a solid foundation.

Comment: Looks great. Could you help me understand why is was doing that? Why would <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> work all this time and suddenly not on this website?

Comment: Each mobile OS has its own rendering quirks and they can change, depending on the width of your site. For example, iOS scales up websites that are thinner than 980 pixels, but doesn't scale them down. That's because the "device width" of an iPhone is 980. On the Android OS, the device width is usually your actual resolution (this is why it reformats text when you zoom in). Setting it to the actual width of your site standardises it across the two platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
```

besides your

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

(or change 320 to whatever makes sense)

Here's a working example, you can check its source code:

http://m.qrdroid.com